# What is the difference between yielding a coroutine function call and yielding a startcoroutine call

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

Unity coroutines can be chained together sequentially using something like the following

```
private void IEnumerator Outer()
{
    yield return StartCoroutine(Inner());
}

private void IEnumerator Inner() { yield break; }
```

However, the following also seems to do the same thing

```
private void IEnumerator Outer()
{
    yield return Inner();
}
```

What actually is the difference between the two methods, is one preferred over the other.
I have only really seen the first in examples but the second has some really key benefits it seems (mainly not needing a monobehaviour to call `StartCoroutine` on)

Comment: My question is specifically about unity coroutines, not c#'s iterators in general

Answer (score 0):

Fast googling results in [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/coroutines-which-call-other-coroutines.1020121/) with good explanations (IMO).